# MeteorJS perform action when window closes

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to perform an action when the user closes their browser.

I have tried use https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status hooks. Mainly the `UserStatus.events.on('connectionLogout')` but this event gets fired when you refresh the page.

I also tried `window.beforeunload` but that too also gets called on every page refresh.

Is there something that allows me to perform an action when someone closes a browser?

Answer (score 0):

So for clarification you want something to happen when the entire browser closes-- I exit my chrome browser?

Or when I leave your page? 
Or when I close the tab/window in which your page was contained? (But browser is still running with other pages)